# How did Vesper show users wallpaper without UIApplicationIsOpaque key?

Tags: ios7, uiwindow, uiapplication

An app named [Vesper](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vesper-simple-elegant-notes/id655895325?mt=8) was updated for iOS 7 and shows the user's wallpaper on iOS 7. I have found that using UIApplicationIsOpaque key and UIBackgroundStyleLightBlur can show the users background but will not pass validation. Vesper passed validation and passed Apple. I did upload this question to the dev forums, but apple has taken it down.

Comment: This seems like a subjective and/or "what's your opinion" type question. To get the real answer, you'd likely have to ask the App Review gnomes for clarification on this.

Comment: There was an answer, but I didn't have a chance to see it before Apple removed the discussion before I could write it down

Comment: I think that is how they did it... either it got through because of Gruber's klout or maybe they appealed or maybe it got through because it's being used subtly. Maybe apple wants to stop people from just having their entire app be completely transparent.

Comment: I noticed this in Vesper and Twitterific but it appears that they have both been updated and this feature has been removed. Let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: Ah, I did not know that Twitterific had this. Apple probably told them they had to resubmit after people asked questions:P They took my discussion on the forums off about this with an answer around apple. I found it on github now though

Comment: I don't think it's been removed from Vesper. They even use it as one of the App Store screenshots.

Comment: @MaxHasADHD where on github did you find the response?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/steventroughtonsmith/6763213

Answer (score 10):

Brent Simmons has written [a blog post](http://vesperapp.co/blog/how-to-make-a-vesper-1-007/) explaining it. It seems like they didn't use UIApplicationIsOpaque key.

> **The Sidebar**
>
> In 1.0 our sidebar menu included a bit of top and bottom
>   padding to blend into the black of the status bar and — along with a
>   touch of shadow from the list view — give a sense of depth, as if the
>   sidebar were always sitting behind the list view. iOS 7′s unified
>   status bar meant that we didn’t have that same black to play against,
>   so we had to rethink our approach. We started looking at Apple’s
>   built-in iOS 7 apps for inspiration, and two things jumped out at us:
>   Safari and Passbook.
>
> Over in Safari, when you tap into open pages view you can see your own
>   homescreen wallpaper blurred through in the background. It’s subtle,
>   but it’s a very nice touch.
>
> We loved the idea and wanted to try it out in our sidebar to see how
>   it would look. Because Apple doesn’t provide an API for live blurring
>   of images, we managed to fake our way around it by dropping a giant
>   live-blur-enabled toolbar behind the sidebar view. It looked fantastic
>   on an iPhone 5, but live blur isn’t supported at all on older phones,
>   where the sidebar fell back to using the unblurred home screen.
>
> Meanwhile, Passbook’s passes float over an unblurred (but darkened)
>   homescreen, making them feel more like widgets floating over the
>   wallpaper like apps in the multi-tasking view. We decided to try that
>   approach and see what worked.
>
> We went through a ton of iteration to find the right opacity for the
>   tinted window view, and for the selected state. Whatever we did would
>   need to look good regardless of the user’s wallpaper, and the effect
>   should be pleasant but not distracting. This is, after all, a menu. To
>   keep things weighted appropriately with the effect, we also chose not
>   to iOS 7-ify the sidebar icons. They should feel a little hefty to
>   stand out.
>
> What started as an “oh crap, what are we going to do” design problem
>   turned into our favorite view in the entire app. Not only was a it
>   neat to look at (especially with the sense of depth given by the
>   homescreen parallax effect), but it gave Vesper a human touch. When
>   you open the sidebar, you’re seeing your own wallpaper. Something you
>   chose. It felt personal. Moreover, it felt very true to iOS 7.
>
> Unfortunately, we didn’t realize until too late that the API needed to
>   pull off the effect is undocumented by Apple. We’ve filed the
>   appropriate radars and made requests to people at Apple. Our hope is
>   that the API becomes available soon and we can return to what we think
>   is a pretty great design.

Comment: Anyone knows if this is still possible with iOS 8/9?

Comment: @RobertoAndrade seems they removed it a while back