# Ios 7 dialer text effect

Tags: objective-c, ios7

How do you get the effect of light text on a dark background as seen in the IOS 7 dialer or the password on the lock screen?

[image: light-text-on-darkbackground]

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to access the background colour in iOS 7 for third party apps. Maybe one day Apple will open the API to access that, but for now we can't do it.

Here's a [discussion about it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19062345/361247).

Comment: the background in this case doesn't hast to be the wallpaper. it can be some custom picture or anything else. so the question would be how to implement a similar effect in a easier way.